# Can not push data to firestore emulator

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am new to firebase. And I am not able to push data to firestore emulator.
Below is the code that I am using to push the data. 'SaveFireStore' is the function which should send data to emulator.I am using iPhone simulator.

````
import {View, Button} from 'react-native';
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
// Initialize Firebase
const config = {
  apiKey: 'KEY',
  authDomain: '',
  databaseURL: '',
  projectId: '',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: '',
  appId: '',
};
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  const db = firestore();
  db.settings({host: 'localhost:8080', ssl: false});
} else {
  firebase.app(); // if already initialized, use that one
}

const App = () => {
  const SaveFireStore = async () => {
    const result = await firestore().collection('testing').doc().set({});
    console.log('Result = ', result);
  };
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Button title="press" onPress={() => SaveFireStore()} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;```
````

Answer (score 1):

I am able to push the data to firestore emulator.
I created an android project(Not the web project) on firebase.
I just added following line before setting the data in the collections.

firestore().settings({ host: "localhost:8080", ssl: false });

Pay attention to the host string its not 'http://localhost:8080'.If I tried to use http://localhost:8080 then app crashed.

Comment: check this out it will teach you everything u need https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/cloud-firestore/part-1-introduction